# Why won't my breed walk?

Tags: netlogo

I am building a model population within a bioreactor, building on a basic tutorial telling how to eat, reproduce, and die, etc.  While tinkering, my turtles stopped walking.  I suspect it has to do with how to ask the different breeds to do things?

Edit: For some reason my contaminants aren't "wheels" either

```
turtles-own [ energy ]  
patches-own [ nutrition ]
breed [ Xanthomonas Xanthomona ]
breed [ contaminants contaminant ]

globals 
[ xanthan biomass ]

to setup
  clear-all
  setup-patches
  set-default-shape Xanthomonas "bug"
  set-default-shape contaminants "wheel"
  crt num-Xanthomonas
  [set color yellow
    set energy 10 
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  foul
  determine-biomass
   reset-ticks
    ;; begins defining a procedure named "setup"
    ;; resets the world to an initial, empty state
    ;; creates 100 turtles, they start out standing at the origin 0,0
    ;; set default shape so I don't have to tell it every time
    ;; A turtle's color variable is random until specified
    ;; setxy command with next two numbers as inputs
    ;; chooses random reporters for allowable x and y coordinates
End

to setup-patches 
  ask patches
  [ set pcolor green
    set nutrition 50
  ]
  ;; every patch starts with 50 nutrition, the color indicates it for us
end

to foul
  set-default-shape contaminants "wheel"
  if Contamination?
  [ crt num-contaminants
    [ set color red
        setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
  compete ]
end

to go
  if ticks >= 2000 [ stop ]
  if count turtles > 2000 [stop]
  if count turtles = 0 [stop]
    feed
  move-turtles
  ask turtles 
  [eat-glucose]
  ask Xanthomonas
  [reproduce]
  check-death
    tick
end

to determine-biomass
  ifelse Contamination?
    [set biomass num-Xanthomonas + num-contaminants
    ]
        [set biomass num-Xanthomonas ]
end 

to move-turtles   
  ;; says that each turtle should run the commands in the brackets
  ;; random doesn't include the number you give it as a possible result
  ;; uses a reporter, each turtle picks a random whole number between 0 and 359
  ;; makes the turtle move forward one step
  ;;specify what you're defining will lose 1 energy per step
 ask Xanthomonas
 [ right random 360
   forward 1
   set energy energy - 1 ]
end

to Feed
  if Continuous-feed?
    [ ask patches
      [if random 100 < 3
      [set pcolor green
    set nutrition nutrition + 50
      ] ] ]
end

to eat-glucose
  ask Xanthomonas
   [ if pcolor = green 
    [ set energy energy + 10
      set nutrition nutrition - 50
      set pcolor gray
      set biomass biomass + 1
    ] ]
  ifelse show-energy?
    [ set label energy ]
    [ set label "" ]
  ;;ask turtles before "if"
  ;;if when true, and only then will the turtle run the commands inside the brackets (otherwise it skips them)
  ;;true/false questions, if true, will do first set of brackets
  ;;false means turtle runs commands in second set of bracket
  ;;energy (elements) will default to zero
end

to reproduce
  ask Xanthomonas
  [ if energy > 50
    [set energy energy - 50
      set xanthan xanthan + 1
      hatch-Xanthomonas 1
      [set biomass biomass + 1
        rt random-float 360 fd 1
      ] ] ]
  end

  to check-death
    ask Xanthomonas
    [ if energy < 0 
      [ die ]
    ]
 end

to reinoculate
    ask patches [
      if random 100 < 10 
      [ set pcolor green 
      ]
    ]
end

to Contaminate
  crt num-contaminants
  [ set color red
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
end

to compete
  ask contaminants
  [ if energy > 50
    [set energy energy - 50
      set xanthan xanthan + 1
      hatch-contaminants 1
      [ set color red 
        set biomass biomass + 1
        rt random-float 360 fd 1
      ] ] ]
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay, your basic problem is the `crt` command. This is short for `create-turtles`. You have two breeds here and you have defined them. However, when you create the turtles, you are not telling NetLogo which breed to create.

What this means is that you need to make a couple of minor changes to specify the breed. If you look in the dictionary, you will see the command is `create-<breed>`. Where you have `crt num-Xanthomonas`, change it to `create-Xanthomonas num-Xanthomonas` and similarly where you create the contaminants.